# Python - how to parse 'prop name' elements in xml

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <autostart version="2.0">
    <FileState>0</FileState>
    <FileTemplate clsid="{6F6FBFC1-3F14-46CA-A269}">
    <properties>
        <obj name="TypeSettings" clsid="{6F6FBFC1-3F14-46CA-A269}">
            <properties>
                <prop name="Enumerator" type="8">en0</prop>
                <prop name="Name" type="8">en0</prop>
                <prop name="Type" type="3">1</prop>
            </properties>
        </obj>
        <obj name="GeneralSettings" clsid="{6F6FBFC1-3F14-46CA-A269}">
            <properties>
                <prop name="BufferSize" type="21">524288000</prop>
                <prop name="FilePattern" type="8">auto_eth0</prop>
                <prop name="FileSize" type="21">1048576</prop>
                <prop name="MaxFileAge" type="11">-1</prop>
                <prop name="MaxTotalFileSize" type="11">0</prop>
                <prop name="Name" type="8">auto-en0</prop>
                <prop name="Owner" type="8">root</prop>
            </properties>
        </obj>
    </properties>
       </FileTemplate>
   </autostart>
```

I want to get attribute values for properties under 'GeneralSettings', I tried the following code but didn't work for me. Is there an easier parser to use?

```
    >>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    >>> tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
    >>> doc = tree.getroot()
    >>> 
    >>> for elem in doc.findall('autostart/FileTemplate/properties/obj/properties/prop'):
    ...     print elem.get('name="BufferSize"'), elem.text
    ... 
    >>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the path expression. Here my attempt:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

doc = ET.parse('test.xml')
for prop_node in doc.iterfind('FileTemplate/properties/obj[@name="GeneralSettings"]/properties/prop[@name="BufferSize"]'):
    print 'Name:', prop_node.get('name'),
    print 'Type:', prop_node.get('type'),
    print 'Text:', prop_node.text
```

## Output

> Name: BufferSize Type: 21 Text: 524288000

## Notes

- The above expression specifies the **obj** node whose attribute **name** is **GeneralSettings**.
- For each node found, use the `.get()` method to get each attribute, or you can use the `.items()` method to get them all.

Comment: Got it - thanks:  for prop_node in doc.iterfind('FileTemplate/properties/obj[@name="GeneralSettings"]/properties/prop[@name="BufferSize"]'):
...     print prop_node.text

Comment: I forgot the `[@name="BufferSize"]` part. Added.

Answer (score 0):

I'm mostly familiar with `BeautifulSoup`, which is rather straightforward:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('test.xml') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

gs = soup.find(attrs={'name':'GeneralSettings'})
for prop in gs.findAll('prop'):
    print(prop.text)

524288000
auto_eth0
1048576
-1
0
auto-en0
root
```

That's not to say that `bs4` is the end-all of xml parsing in python, it just has a very friendly API.

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is perfect for this!

```
import bs4
wanted = "BufferedSize"
#doc = your html string
soup = bst.BeautifulSoup(doc)
#get all prop inside properties
props = soup.findall('prop')
for prop in props:
    name = prop["name"]
    if name == wanted:
        print prop["name"], prop.text
```

Let me know if you need anything explained!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have `autostart` in the search path and that's your root. If you modify that line to read:

```
for elem in doc.findall('FileTemplate/properties/obj[@name="GeneralSettings"]/properties/prop[@name="BufferSize"]'):
    print elem.text
```

should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me on the search path; however, I tried your suggestion to do but it would get all props instead of just the one for 'Buffersize': None en0
None en0
None 1
None 524288000
None auto_eth0
None 1048576
None -1
None 0
None auto-en0
None root

Comment: None en0
None en0
None 1
None 524288000
None auto_eth0
None 1048576
None -1
None 0
None auto-en0
None root

Comment: Try this:
`for elem in doc.findall('FileTemplate/properties/obj[@name="GeneralSettings"]/properties/prop[@name="BufferSize"]'):
    print elem.text`

Comment: No prob. glad to help.